# Vue Laravel Dynamic Dependent Dropdown

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to get the Decoration types according to the house area types. I got the house area types but failed to get the decoration types. In Vue dev tool the "houseTypes" are showing an array but the "decorTypes" are showing "Reactive". I am also dynamically creating rows and removing them. for that i took an array

my vue file is--

```
<template>
<div v-for="(tab,k) in tabs" :key="k" >
<table class="table table-borderless col-md-12">
  <thead>
    <th>HouseAreaType</th>
    <th>DecorationType</th>
   
    <th>Action</th>
    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <select
        v-model="tab.selectedHouseType"
       
        class="form-control select2"
        id="houseType1"
        required
        name="houseAreaTypeId"
      >
        <option
          v-for="houseType in houseTypes"
          :key="houseType.id"
          :value="houseType.id"
        >
          {{ houseType.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select
        v-model="selectedDecor"
        @change="getDescription()"
        class="form-control select2"
        required
      >
        <option
          selected
          v-for="decorType in decorTypes"
          :key="decorType.id"
          :value="decorType.id"
        >
          {{ decorType.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </td>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-success"
        value="Add More"
        @click="addRow"
      />
    </td>
    <td >
      <input
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-danger"
        value="Remove"
        @click="removeRow(k,tab)"
      />
    </td>
      </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
 </template>
  <script type="module">
    export default {
     data() {
   return {
  tabs: [{
    rate:"",
  selectedHouseType: "",
  selectedDecor: "",
  
  }],
  tabCounter: 0,
  houseTypes: {},
  decorTypes: {},
 
      };
     },
 methods: {
    getHouseTypes() {
  axios.get("/api/houseTypes").then((response) => {
    this.houseTypes = response.data;
    // this.productForm.colors = response.data;
  });
},
addRow() {
  this.tabs.push(this.tabCounter++);
},
removeRow(index,tab) {
  var idx = this.tabs.indexOf(tab);
        console.log(idx, index);
            this.tabs.splice(idx, 1);
           },
 },
 watch: {
'tab.selectedHouseType': function (value){
    axios.get('/api/decorTypes?houseAreaTypeId=' + value)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.decorTypes = response.data.data;
    });
},

    },
  mounted() {
    this.getHouseTypes();
  }, 
  };
</script>
```

my api.php---

```
Route::get('/houseTypes',[CartController::class,'getHouseTypes'])->name('houseTypes');
Route::get('/decorTypes',[CartController::class,'getDecorTypes'])->name('decorTypes');
```

my CartController--

```
public function getHouseTypes()
{
    $houseTypes = HouseAreaType::all();
    return response()->json($houseTypes);
}
public function getDecorTypes()
{
    $houseAreaTypeId = request('houseAreaTypeId');

    $decorTypes = DecorationType::where('houseAreaTypeId',$houseAreaTypeId)->get();
    return response()->json($decorTypes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solved iy.

created a method getDecor()..

```
<select
        v-model="tab.selectedHouseType"
        @change="getDecor()"
        class="form-control select2"
        id="houseType1"
        required
        name="houseAreaTypeId"
      >
```

in the mthods--

```
      getDecor(){
            axios.get('/api/decorTypes', {
                params: {
                    houseAreaTypeId: this.tabs[this.tabs.length- 
                    1].selectedHouseType
                }
            }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
                
            }.bind(this));
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).